# ¿Es posible optimizar esta función de extracción de cadenas de caracteres usando regex en R?

Tags: r, regex, funciones, programación-funcional

Supongamos que tenemos una cadena de apellidos como la siguiente:

```
nom <- c("Perez Conchito", "Juanin Juanharry", "Von Bola")
```

Diseñé una pequeña función para extraer cada parte de la cadena y luego reunirlas en una data.frame con dos columnas.

```
extract_apellidos <- function(x) {
    first_split <- strsplit(x, " ")
    split_un <- unlist(first_split)
    primer_ap <- split_un[c(TRUE, FALSE)] #Nos da el primer apellido
    segundo_ap <- split_un[c(FALSE,TRUE)] #Nos da el segundo apellido
    data.frame(Primer_ap=primer_ap, Segundo_ap=segundo_ap)
}

extract_apellidos(nom)


  Primer_ap Segundo_ap
1     Perez   Conchito
2    Juanin  Juanharry
3       Von       Bola
```

Como se aprecia, funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, quisiera saber si es posible optimizarla empleando funciones regulares ya que intuyo que eso me permitiría reducir el número de pasos empleados.
De antemano, agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alejandro, al menos con R base, cualquier cosa que hagas con expresiones regulares, vas a terminar con una lista, es decir en el mismo lugar en que te deja:

```
first_split <- strsplit(x, " ")
```

Por ejemplo con:

```
regmatches(nom, regexec("(.*)\\s(.*)", nom))
```

hemos obtenido una lista, con vectores de 3 elementos, la cadena completa que hizo "match" y la primera y segunda palabra. No logras ganar prácticamente nada a tu rutina (revisa igual que tienes un error `eto_todos` no existe, entiendo debería ser `split_un`). Por otro lado, usar expresiones regulares para separar palabras a partir de un espacio, es innecesariamente complejo.

Otra cosa es, si usas `stringr`, ya que puedes aprovechar `str_match()` con los grupos de captura y que su salida, ya es una matriz, con esto sí, puedes acortar un poco el código:

```
library("stringr")

match_df <- as.data.frame(str_match(nom, "(.*)\\s(.*)"))[, c(2,3)]
colnames(match_df) <- c("Primer_ap", "Segundo_ap")
```

Pero además tiene una ventaja extra: al respetar la metodología de `tydverse`, el retorno es consistente con el objeto de entrada, de modo que si no encuentra un patrón, de todas formas retornará una fila para dicho caso:

```
nom <- c("Perez Conchito", "Juanin Juanharry", "Von Bola", "Pedro")
match_df <- as.data.frame(str_match(nom, "(.*)\\s(.*)"))[, c(2,3)]
colnames(match_df) <- c("Primer_ap", "Segundo_ap")
match_df

  Primer_ap Segundo_ap
1     Perez   Conchito
2    Juanin  Juanharry
3       Von       Bola
4      <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Sí pensé que le agregaba algo de complejidad innecesaria. Sin embargo, trato de entender mejor expresiones regulares porque sigue siendo un tema oscuro para mí, razón por la cual trato de emplearla incluso en situaciones donde no resultan tan relevantes. ¡Gracias!